# remove a row from a dataframe if any row value is in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1 with one column

```
{0:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11]}
```

df2 with two col

```
{0:[100,4,6,7],1:[1,3,4,7]}
```

i have to remove rows from df1 with value in any column in df2

ressult dataframe

```
df3 = [2,5,11]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df1[~df1[0].isin(df2.values.flatten())]
```

output:

[image]

---

for large data frames, I have done the following simple benchmark:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def anky_91(t):
    df1, df2 =  t
    df1[~df1[0].isin(df2.stack())]

@b.add_function()
def kederrac(t):  
    df1, df2 =  t
    df1[~df1[0].isin(df2.values.flatten())]

@b.add_function()   
def yatu(t):
    df1, df2 =  t
    df1[~df1.squeeze().isin(df2.stack())]


@b.add_arguments('NUmber of rows ind df')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 18):
        size = 2**exp
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, size // 10 or 10,size= (size , 1)))
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, size // 10 or 10 ,size=(size , 2)))
        yield size, (df1, df2)

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Comment: can you give me an idea how well in terms of memory will it work for large dataframes

Comment: @aryansingh  I have done a simple benchmark you can check my update

Comment: one more thing , in df1[~df1[0].isin(df2.values.flatten())] if i df1 has more than 1 col is it  possible to give it  ~df1[[0,1]] will this work ?

Comment: i have asked another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964693/remove-a-row-from-a-dataframe-if-any-row-value-is-in-another-dataframe-with-da

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1[~df1.squeeze().isin(df2.stack())]

    0
1   2
4   5
7  11
```

Answer (score 2):

Stack the second dataframe and do an isin on the first column , then invert

```
df1[~df1[0].isin(df2.stack())]
```

---

```
    0
1   2
4   5
7  11
```

Comment: can you give me an idea about  how well in terms of memory will it work for large dataframes