# remove a row from a dataframe if any row value is in another dataframe , with dataframes having multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I hava two data frames :

```
df1 = {0:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11],1:[100,20,7]}

df2 = {0:[100,4,6,7],1:[1,3,4,7]}
```

i have to remove  rows from df1 that occurs in any row of df2

result dataframe

```
df3 = [2,5,11,20]
```

Comment: I think for first `[100,20,7]` is wrong, because necessary same number of values of both lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten values by `np.ravel` and get difference by [`np.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11],1:[100,20,7,1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:[100,4,6,7],1:[1,3,4,7]})

L = np.setdiff1d(np.ravel(df1), np.ravel(df2)).tolist()
print (L)
[2, 5, 11, 20]
```

Or difference of sets:

```
L = list(set(df1.stack()) - set(df2.stack()))
print (L)
[2, 11, 20, 5]
```

Comment: Given the orignal code L gives - [{0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11], 1: [100, 20, 7]}]